# Linking Bintray Package to JCenter

Tags: bintray, jcenter

I have a package in Bintray called "tripod" which is here:

https://bintray.com/bbende/bbende-maven/tripod

The tripod package is a Maven project with a standard multi-module setup where the root pom artifactId is tripod, with sub-modules of tripod-search-api, tripod-search-solr, and tripod-search-lucene.

In my personal Maven repo, all of these artifacts are published under the groupId com.bbende.tripod as shown here:

https://dl.bintray.com/bbende/bbende-maven/com/bbende/tripod/

When I requested to link the tripod package to JCenter using the link on the main package page for "tripod" it ended up linking only the artifact for the top-level pom as seen here:

http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/bbende/tripod/

How are you supposed to get the entire package linked to JCenter?

I believe this is the same issue here which looks like it requires manual intervention from someone at bintray/jcenter:

[Bintray does not sync one of the artifacts of the package to the jcenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468385/bintray-does-not-sync-one-of-the-artifacts-of-the-package-to-the-jcenter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Bintray package is linked to jcenter with a specific path prefix, so that all submodules and versions under the base path will automatically be linked to jcenter without further manual intervention.

It seems like your package is linked under the base path containing only one of the submodules, therefore, the other submodules are not linked to jcenter.

In such cases, you should contact JFrog support in order to fix the inclusion path. In this case, we have already fixed it and all submodules are correctly linked to jcenter.

Best Regards,
Itamar