# bintray - publishing multi-module Gradle artifacts to JCenter

Tags: gradle, bintray, jcenter

[my project](https://github.com/thewca/tnoodle-lib) is organized as a Gradle multi-project build with five Java modules/sub-projects. When building them, it results in five different JAR artifacts.

Four of those artifacts contain helper classes or small, isolated portions of code doing very specific things (for example efficient graph search that is optimised towards my specific use case domain). Only one project is the "main" artifiact that makes sense to use in a standalone way, but all five artifacts are required for it to run.

I would like to make [this core artifact](https://bintray.com/beta/#/thewca/tnoodle-lib/scrambles?tab=overview) available to users, and I have been successful in uploading all five artifacts to a Bintray account. When mirroring to JCenter, I have two concerns:

1. Do I have to actively link all 5 projects to JCenter, or is there a way to only expose the "core" artifact to the general public?
2. What does the "Is Pom Project" checkbox do? As I understand it, Gradle creates POM files for every Maven publication artifact, so this box should always be checked for Maven-style builds. Is this correct?

[image: screenshot ad (2)]

(potential duplicate that does not contain a solution apart from "I work at Bintray and I fixed it for you in our system!": [Linking Bintray Package to JCenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260212/linking-bintray-package-to-jcenter))

Thanks!
- Gregor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I can answer all.

> 1. Do I have to actively link all 5 projects to JCenter, or is there a way to only expose the "core" artifact to the general public?

As the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260212/linking-bintray-package-to-jcenter) you have attached says, it is linked on path level, this means that if you include `org/worldcubeassociation/tnoodle/lib-scrambles/` as the path, then **only those modules** will be linked to Jcenter.

> 2. What does the "Is Pom Project" checkbox do? As I understand it, Gradle creates POM files for every Maven publication artifact, so this box should always be checked for Maven-style builds. Is this correct?

Yes, you are correct. The POM file is created and uploaded. You can see the POM file in your [path](https://dl.bintray.com/thewca/tnoodle-lib/org/worldcubeassociation/tnoodle/lib-scrambles/0.16.3/).

For more information you can always check the central repositories [guide](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/BT/Central+Repositories).

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation about "linking on path level" makes sense by itself, but I'm having a hard time getting a grasp of how I can use this to my advantage. The JCenter path is nothing that I have influence on (as far as I am concerned), so how can I achieve the desired effect of publishing the four "helper libraries" under the path of `lib-scrambles` in this exact case?

Comment: I'll try to explain. Let us say that you include your package to JCenter, and the path you supply is `org/worldcubeassociation/tnoodle/lib-scrambles/`. this is clear, and you will have all of your VERSIONS in JCenter. **BUT** If you add `org/worldcubeassociation/tnoodle/` (without the `lib-scrambles`) it means that all the PATHS will be added. Meaning the artifacts under that path will be available to download from JCenter.

Comment: Gotcha, now all I have to do is wrap my head around expressing that concept in my Gralde multi-project build. Thanks!

Comment: You can ping me for questions! I'll try to help.